# Reading Property value through Properties class

Tags: java, properties

I have imported an existing project into Eclipse workspace.
I have this line of code inside my existing Project.

```
String   eod = Props.getProperty("client.eod", 5);
```

What is the exact meaning of the argument `5` in this call?
My guess is that if there is no property with the name `client.eod` whether it will set the value 5 to it. Could anybody confirm or disprove it?

Comment: This can be easily found in the java doc.

Comment: By saying it do you mean property or string object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You are correct. But it is `getProperty(String, String)`

```
String   eod = Props.getProperty("client.eod", "5");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says that the method signature is

```
public String getProperty(String key, String defaultValue)
```

hence the second argument is the default value; the docs also adds that

> The method returns the default value argument if the property is not
>   found.

so it works as you imagined.

Answer (score -1):

```
    String   eod = Props.getProperty("client.eod", 5);
   System.out.println("eod: "+eod);
```

Ya This will set the client.eod for 5.

If the value is not defined in properties file then it sets the default value.

so It gives output as below

```
eod:5
```

Comment: The answer will be "5" only when there is not property called "client.eod" in the props file. Not always it returns "5".

Comment: I know.If the value is not defined in properties file then it sets the default value.I thought i have mention that.Its default argument.